# How to change the php version in Lando 8.1.2

Tags: php, composer-php, lando

This is my first question. I'm a beginner. I'm working in a wordpress project with sage. When I try to run the template, there is a mistake:

[image]

The composer version is ok, but Lando version is php7.4 and I need the php8.1 version.

I've tried to change the php version in lando.yml and then using the command lando rebuild but it doesn't work. I'm also working with manjaro. Any help will be welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Remove the _lord_ theme from the Wordpress project and then it should work again. That theme looks horribly misconfigured anyway, so you're perhaps putting your server at risk if you leave it on the system (so it not only breaks Worpdress). Just kill it with fire.

Answer (score 5):

You could start with `lando init`

```bash
$ lando init
? From where should we get your app's codebase? remote git repo or archive
? Please enter the URL of the git repo or tar archive containing your application code https://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz
? What recipe do you want to use? wordpress
? Where is your webroot relative to the init destination? wordpress
? What do you want to call this app? my-wordpress-app
```

Then you get a `.lando.yml` where you need to specify the php version for the `appserver`.

```yaml
# .lando.yml
name: my-wordpress-app
recipe: wordpress
config:
  webroot: wordpress
services:
  appserver:
    type: php:8.1 #add these lines
```

You also might need to destroy and rebuild after making that php-change:

```bash
lando destroy -y && lando start
```

Sources:

- https://docs.lando.dev/php
- https://docs.lando.dev/wordpress/config.html#choosing-a-php-version

Answer (score 3):

For pantheon recipes:

I hope this saves someone as confused as I was some time. I changed my .lando file to 8.1 and rebuilt, then tried destroy & start. Both failed.

It turned out I had to go to pantheon.yml and change php version there also. I suppose that's a 'dependency' which holds lando back.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please show how that looks like wich code in your answer and please reference offical documentation material by linking it for the configuration directives and the commands as you wrote you did so it becomes more clear for other persons what you had in mind when writing the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The error you see is because the environment you are in on that point is php 7.4. And in your composer.json you already have 8.2. The file which throws the error is **auto generated** when you did "composer install" and in your composer.json you had already upgraded php to 8.2 probably.

What I did in my Lando project is the following:

To be able to switch between 2 lando's with php 7.4 and 8.2 back and forth (like when switching git branches and sometimes work in 7.4 and sometimes 8.2) you need to change the **name** on top of the .lando.yml file. this makes new containers and also keeps your old php 7.4 containers to easily switch back

- Stop the current running lando first

`lando stop`

- Change the "name" on top of your .lando.yml file (Only necessary if you think you'll ever want to switch to 7.4 again)

```
# Old name
name: my-project

# Make sure the running lando has been stopped first, "lando stop" will look
# for the current "name" to stop things
# Change to:
name: my-project-php-8-2
```

Change everything which points to php 7.4 to 8.2

```
config:
    # Old
    php: '7.4'
    # Change to:
    php: '8.2'
services:
    appserver:
        overrides:
            # Old
            image: my-project/php:7.4-apache-4
            # Change to:
            image: my-project/php:8.2-apache-4
```

Maybe there is a Dockerfile too

```
# Old
FROM devwithlando/php:7.4-apache-4
# Change to:
FROM devwithlando/php:8.2-apache-4
```

If you want to search your whole project for occurrences of `7.4` you can use this regex:

`[^0-9A-Za-z]7(|\.|-|_)4[^0-9A-Za-z]`

I found other places which I needed to update php version like

- composer.json
- gitlab-ci.yml
- Maybe you have more files which need the new php version?

If everything is updated correctly I would do this:

- Throw away your vendor/ folder
- One of these:
  **OR** `lando start` (which makes new containers because the Lando "name" changed) 
  **OR** `lando rebuild` if you did not change your "name" on top of the .lando.yml file (Maybe you need destroy and start, not 100% sure)
- Update your composer.json file and check if all bundles are able to use php 8.2
- `composer install` (inside your lando with the new php 8.2 version)

An extra thing to take care is with changing the name of your database host

```
# Old:
DB_HOST=database.myproject.internal
# Change to new:
DB_HOST=database.myprojectphp82.internal
```

Answer (score 0):

To use particular PHP version you can add in config - except using in

```yaml
services:
  myservice:
```

Example Wordpress `lando.yml`

```yaml
name: testwordpress
recipe: wordpress
config:
  webroot: .  
  php: 8.1
```

For details on particular `PHP` version you can check lando official [guide](https://docs.lando.dev/php/)

Answer (score 0):

Change the app PHP version to 8.1 in .lando.yml as below:

```
name: my_app
config:
  webroot: web
  php: '8.1'
```

And then run **lando rebuild** to get an updated php container.

**Warning:** **lando destroy** will *destroy* your app (The files (eg the git repo) for the app will not be removed but any database or index information **will be irretrievably lost**.) **So Do NOT use it** unless you know what you're doing.